# problem changing folder icons using desktop.ini

Tags: python, windows, desktop.ini

so i want to change desktop.ini to use custom folder icons

```
with open("desktop.ini", "a") as f:         
    f.write("[.ShellClassInfo]"+"\n")
    f.write("IconResource="+logo+",0")
 
os.system("attrib +h +s desktop.ini")
```

the desktop.ini file gets edited, its both hidden and a system file, and the text is identical to the text if i changed the icons manually, but it still doesn't work.
any ideas?

Comment: There is probably some Windows API you have to use to change or create this file — google is your friend.

Comment: Maybe Windows will recognize this if you reboot the machine.

Comment: According to https://superuser.com/questions/410085/is-there-a-way-to-easily-set-the-icon-a-folder-uses/410091#410091 you might have to set the read-only attribute on the folder.

Comment: yes just solved it, i have to attribute system file to the containing folder also. ty for the help :)